# onomatopoeia＋した as modifiers

Tags: tense, onomatopoeia, modification

Examples like あっさりした味、ちょっとした風邪、きちんとした身なり have onomatopoeia＋した as modifiers. There do not seem to be examples with した replaced with する. Is this observation correct? If so, is there a reason why した is used instead of する?

Comment: @naruto Partly. The answers could explain きちんとした身なり, since dressing up in the past leads to 身なり as the current state. But I can't seem how ちょっとした風邪 can be similarly explained.

Comment: I think ちょっとした should be classified as a fixed 連体詞 (attributive) that does not follow regular grammar rules. [Dictionaries](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%80%E5%AF%B8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F/) [say so](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E5%AF%B8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F). Other 連体詞 include 大きな, 大した, 同じ and 色んな.